# Add new brush property in VS WPF designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm creating a new button control, and I wanted to create a new property under the brushes section where I can set the hovercolor. Anyone know how you would do this?

Answer (score 1):

The **simplest way** to add a property that will appear in the "Brush" section of the *Properties* panel is to - define a `Brush` property in control's class code:

```
  public partial class MyFancyControl : UserControl
  {
     // ...

     public Brush FancyBrush
        {
           get;
           set;
        }

     // ...
  }
```

The property will show in "Brush" section with no further action (at least it does in my VS2013, see below).

While such a property will work just fine in most cases, the **proper way** to do it is to define it as a `DependencyProperty`:

```
  public partial class MyFancyControl : UserControl
  {
     // ...

     public Brush FancyBrush
     {
        get
        {
           return (Brush)GetValue(FancyBrushProperty);
        }
        set
        {
           SetValue(FancyBrushProperty, value);
        }
     }

     public static readonly DependencyProperty FancyBrushProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("FancyBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(IntUpDown), new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush)));

     // ...
  }
```

Using `DependencyProperty` will enable binding and other "advanced" stuff.

Tip: Use VS Intellisense helpers to avoid need to type all the surrounding code - type "propdp" and press `Tab` twice.

To **make sure** the property will show up in the correct section of the *Properties* panel, add the `Category` attribute:

```
     [System.ComponentModel.Category("Brush")]
     public Brush FancyBrush
     {...
```

Again, this seems to work automatically for `Brush` type so it may not be necessary.

You can also add a `Description` attribute that will show in the tooltip in the *Properties* panel:

```
      [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets a brush that defines fancy look of the control.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the brush and add it as a resource something like:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MouseOverColor" Color="#FFFFFFF"/>
```

Then in the template triggers in your button template:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Background" Value="StaticResource MouseOverColor}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Here is a simple button from in a resource dictionary file that uses defined brushes:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionHighlightBrush" Color="#282828"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectionHighlightTextBrush" Color="White"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ForegroundBrush" Color="#282828"/>     
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlBackgroundBrush" Color="White"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlBorderBrush" Color="#C0C0C0" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ControlBorderBrush}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="temp" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border x:Name="bd" CornerRadius="3" 
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectionHighlightBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SelectionHighlightTextBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```